# Tomee Server Startup Error Database lock acquisition failure even when hsql is not configured in application

Tags: tomcat, kubernetes, hsqldb, apache-tomee, hashicorp-vault

I have an application that runs on kubernetes cluster on tomee container.

Application was running fine and still running fine with below exception now:

```
INFO: Configuring Service(id=My Stateful Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateful Container)
Feb 24, 2021 11:00:12 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=My Stateless Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateless Container)
Feb 24, 2021 11:00:12 AM org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentsResolver loadFrom
WARNING: File error: <Deployments dir="apps/"> - Does not exist: /opt/gemalto/lib/tomee/apps
Feb 24, 2021 11:00:12 AM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFO: Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath=false'
Feb 24, 2021 11:00:12 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
Feb 24, 2021 11:00:12 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
Feb 24, 2021 11:00:13 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Resource(id=My DataSource)
Feb 24, 2021 11:00:15 AM org.hsqldb.persist.Logger logSevereEvent
SEVERE: could not reopen database

org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@324c044d[file =<Some path1>/tomee/data/hsqldb/hsqldb.lck, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: openRAF reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: <Some path1>/tomee/data/hsqldb/hsqldb.lck (No such file or directory)
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile.newLockFileLock(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.acquireLock(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:744)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:676)
```

Now the very interesting part is as i mentioned application is running fine still.

What changed is: now application is configured with vault agent to get some secret and provide input to a file to read all dependent secrets on file system.All of this is working fine.

But the above exception I am not able to decipher that why did it introduced into the system...Also the interesting part is there is no change in source code and pom files.The only could be impacting thing is the inside `CATALINA_HOME` we have a keyfile

Now being created by vault and that's it. Please suggest how to get rid of this exception and possible cause of its exception.

And also the reason why tomee is trying to connect to hsql db and looking for this lock file.

Another interesting observation (to me its interesting but for somebody expert it may be a regular stuff)

On regular startup where above mentioned exception is not there the files at catalina home are:

```
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp     2.6K Jun 30  2020 tomcat-users.xsd
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp     2.3K Jun 30  2020 jaspic-providers.xsd
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp     1.1K Jun 30  2020 jaspic-providers.xml
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp     1.4K Jun 30  2020 context.xml
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp     7.3K Jun 30  2020 catalina.properties
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp    12.8K Jun 30  2020 catalina.policy
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp    51.0K Jul 22  2020 web.xml
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp      236 Jul 22  2020 tomee.xml
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp     2.2K Jul 22  2020 tomcat-users.xml.original
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp     2.4K Jul 22  2020 tomcat-users.xml
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp     7.6K Jul 22  2020 server.xml.original
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp     7.8K Jul 22  2020 server.xml.orig
-rw-r--r--    1 trent    grp     5.5K Aug 11  2020 server.xml.patch
drwxr-x---    1 trent    grp     4.0K Aug 11  2020 conf.d
drwxr-xr-x    1 trent    grp     4.0K Aug 11  2020 ..
drwxr-x---    1 trent    grp     4.0K Aug 11  2020 Catalina
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp     3.6K Aug 11  2020 system.properties
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp     7.1K Aug 11  2020 logging.properties
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          18 Dec 11 15:22 securion.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        1.2K Dec 11 15:22 log4j.properties
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        1.2K Feb 24 08:23 tomee.jks
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        2.0K Feb 24 08:23 server.xml
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        1.6K Feb 24 08:23 some.properties
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         605 Feb 24 08:23 log4j2.xml
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        1000 Feb 24 08:23 keyfile
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         814 Feb 24 08:23 keyAdministrator.properties
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        2.9K Feb 24 08:23 config.properties
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        1.7K Feb 24 08:23 certs.keystore
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         751 Feb 24 08:23 cacerts
drwxr-x---    1 trent    gemalto     4.0K Feb 24 08:24 .

While on the container logs where the above exceptions is coming(but the application seeming to be working):
drwxr-x---    1 trent    grp 4.0K Jan  1  2020 Catalina
-rw-r-----    1 trent    grp     6.9K Jan  1  2020 logging.properties
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        1.2K Mar 27  2020 log4j.properties
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         769 Feb 23 10:10 tomee.jks
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        2.0K Feb 23 10:10 server.xml
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        1.6K Feb 23 10:10 some.properties
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         608 Feb 23 10:10 log4j2.xml
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        1000 Feb 23 10:10 keyfile
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         814 Feb 23 10:10 keyAdministrator.properties
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        2.5K Feb 23 10:10 config.properties
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        1.7K Feb 23 10:10 certs.keystore
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         751 Feb 23 10:10 cacerts
drwxr-x---    1 trent    grp     4.0K Feb 23 10:10 .
drwxr-x---    1 trent    grp     4.0K Feb 23 10:10 **openejb.xml**
```

Seems the delta file in first ls out put were getting generated while its generation was prevented in exception based startup.
May be the newly ghostly introduce openejb.xml is causing the trouble as it has the definition of hsql db.But how is it introduced and how to delete it.

Comment: The exception means the server attempts to create a new HSQLDB database and fails (perhaps due to directory access permissions).

Comment: The reason was actually wrong mounting of kubernates mountpath that led to deletion of already existing files and then this led tomee to go for openejb default file and hence the default connection....Soled it somehow...Thanks.